# Reduce foreach loops into a linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var inventionIds = new List<int>();
List<ProductRemunerationReportingPeriodLink> productRemunerationReportingList = 
        GetAllProductRemunerationReportingPeriodByProductId(productId);

foreach (var rptPeriod in productRemunerationReportingList)
{
    var inventionsList = rptPeriod.Inventions;
    foreach (var link in inventionsList)
    {
                int id  = link.Invention.InventionId;
                inventionIds.Add(id);
    }
}

return inventionIds;
```

I want to minimise the two for loopsAny one please provide a nhibernate linq query for this. Any help is much aprreiciated.

Comment: I hope you don't feel i've butchered your question. If people can read it, you'll get better answers.

Comment: Use Resharper as that tool will automatically optimize such loops into linq for you while you write them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your original variable names:

```
var inventionIds =
    productRemunerationReportingList.SelectMany(rptPeriod => rptPeriod.Inventions)
                                    .Select(ProductRemunerationReportingPeriodInvention => ProductRemunerationReportingPeriodInvention.Invention.InventionId)
                                    .ToList();
```

Same with better naming:

```
var inventionIds = GetAllProductRemunerationReportingPeriodByProductId(productId)
                     .SelectMany(p => p.Inventions)
                     .Select(i => i.Invention.InventionId)
                     .ToList();
```

HINT: Length of variable name should correspond to scope in which variable is used. Globally  accessible variables should have nice descriptive names. Variables used in short scopes like lambda should have very short names.

Comment: Thanks man. Your solution worked like charm. Right from morning i am trying with ANY.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> inventionIds = (from rptPeriod in productRemunerationReportingList 
from ProductRemunerationReportingPeriodInvention in rptPeriod.Inventions
select ProductRemunerationReportingPeriodInvention.Invention.InventionId).ToList<int>();
```